# How to call the Color Picker window in Ida Pro from a script?

Tags: ida, idapython, python, ida-plugin

I'm going to make a **python script** that allows you to color **selected** functions - in the right colors.
To do this, I need to programmatically call the ColorPicker window so that the user can select the color he wants.
How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: `QColorDialog` (in `qtproxies.py`) seems to be it, no?

Answer (score 1):

I already made this plugin. But, now I have a problem with the fact that:

```
     # refresh IDA views
     idaapi.refresh_idaview_anyway()
     idaapi.refresh_choosers()
     idc.Refresh()
```

none of this helps.

[image]

I have to manually press the "Refresh" button to redraw the chooser.